# What permissions are required to return rows from information_schema.schemata?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.3, information-schema

In postgres (I'm on 9.3.4) what permissions are required to return rows for

```
select * from information_schema.schemata
```

---

The [9.3 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/infoschema-schemata.html) says "are owned by a currently enabled role". Does that mean the user calling `schemata` must own (or be part of a role that owns) the various schemata?

Later in [9.5 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/infoschema-schemata.html) it says schemata that "the current user has access to (by way of being the owner or having some privilege)".

The account currently trying to run the query and getting 0 rows back has had `grant usage on schema` applied to it.

**What are the privileges that allow a database account to see a schema in the information_schema.schemata` view?**

Comment: Related: [How to check if PostgreSQL public schema exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781952) on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user needs to be the owner of a schema to get any rows from `information_schema.schemata`

```
alter schema $schemaName owner to $user;
```

Or the user needs to be a member of a group that owns the schema

Usage grant is not sufficient. The user does not need to be a superuser. The user can own a table in a schema, but that is not sufficient either.