# PostgreSQL: psql command-line client does not show all schemas

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.3 server. Connecting using an JDBC client (Squirrel) and executing

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
```

shows me all the schemas on the server.

Connecting the same using psql via an SSH session:

```
su -l postgres
psql -U postgres -W -p 5432 -h localhost
```

and the same select shows only a few schemas:

```
schema_name
--------------------
pg_toast
pg_temp_1
pg_toast_temp_1
pg_catalog
public
information_schema
```

There is only one DB instance on the server. Username and password are the same. Why is that? Do I need to configure something for `psql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the client application that makes the results differ, but the database user you're connected with.

In 9.3, `schemata` returns only the schemas that the session's user owns, either directly or indirectly through a granted role.

[The doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/infoschema-schemata.html) says:

> The view schemata contains all schemas in the current database that
>   are owned by a currently enabled role.

Note that it was changed in later versions to be less restrictive.

See [What permissions are required to return rows from information_schema.schemata?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138116) (9.3)
and [How to check if PostgreSQL public schema exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781952) on stackoverflow